# put title of title border to the right in java swing

Tags: java, swing, border

I have a swing form in my program and I used a panel which uses title border as you see in the picture:

[image: net search]

I want to put the title ( marked with red oval ) of title border to the right but I don't want to use `applyComponentOrientation` function because it reorders all my element in the ?panel, is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The place to start is by reading the TitledBorder API.

There are methods like:

```
setTitleJustification(...);
setTitlePosition(...);
```

to help you position the title. I'll let you read the API to find the appropriate values for your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one it has justification method as @camickr said.

```
setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(10,10,10,10,Color.BLACK),"Title",TitledBorder.RIGHT,TitledBorder.TOP));
```